A bash script to list organization policies affecting a google cloud project
In my company we have several organization policies on the org level.  Some on folder level.
I would like to be able to, as an admin, list all organization policies for a google cloud project that has a value different than "google default" for a google cloud project.
For example,
If we have specified at the organization level that the constraint "constraints/run.allowedIngress" is disabled
AND at a parent folde level have a constraint
"constraints/iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation" is enabled
i am trying to list these two policies and their values in the context of a google cloud project.
The goal is to quickly be able to see (and pherhaps) override policies for certain google cloud projects.
Note that examples provided here are only an example.  In my organization we have several organization policies enabled that diverge from google default.
I have tried to run
gcloud resource-manager org-policies list --project=xxx

but it only shows organization overrides for the project. (usually empty)

In the documentation you can ask the effective value (with inheritance evaluation) on a specific constraint. The problem is: you must first query all the available policies and then  iterate on each of them to get the effective value of each. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/reference/orgpolicy/rest/v2/projects.policies/getEffectivePolicy or gcloud resource-manager org-policies describe <policy> --effective
